# Wordpress show content only on certain condition

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I am working on site where I can show its content only for users registered in another DB. I managed to get an API response from the other system if the user exists or not but I don't really know how to continue the process. Can you guys please help me?

PS: I can't authenticate the user in the WP database, and I would like to keep the admin user login the way it is.

this is my API request:

```
$username = '';
$password = '';
$token = '';
$url = "";
$cookie = "h8gkh8.txt";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/' . $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/' . $cookie);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch))
    die(curl_error($ch));

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($response);
$el = $doc->getElementsByTagName("input");

for ($i = 0; $i < $el->length; $i++) {
    $attr = $el->item($i)->getAttribute('name');
    if ($attr == '_csrfhash') {
        $token = $el->item($i)->getAttribute('value');
    }
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$params = array(
    'scemail' => $username,
    'scpassword' => $password,
    '_csrfhash' => $token
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));

$r = curl_exec($ch);


if (curl_errno($ch)) 
    print curl_error($ch);
```

Comment: You want to access data from another database in wordpress?

Comment: nope, i just have a respont from an API, the respons could be nothing, that means the username and password are correct or an error

Answer (score 0):

> For extrnal/custom login you have to use **[authenticate](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/authenticate)** filter.
>   Whenever a login is triggered the authenticate filter is hit and
>   custom logic can be applied to it. The filter can be setup with the
>   following code.

```
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'my_auth', 10, 3 );

function my_auth( $user, $username, $password ){
    return $user;
}
```

The `my_auth` function will replace the built-in authentication method. The authenticate filter sends along three parameters:

1. $user – A WP_User object.
2. $username – From the username text box.
3. $password – From the password text box.

Here is the full `my_auth` code:

```
function my_auth($user, $username, $password)
{
    // Make sure a username and password are present for us to work with
    if ($username == '' || $password == '')
        return;

    /* my_api_section
     * your API code goes here
     * Assuming it returns 0 for username and password missmatch
     * and 1 for match; store the result in $ext_auth['result']
     */


    if ($ext_auth['result'] == 0) {
        // User does not exist,  send back an error message
        $user = new WP_Error('denied', __("ERROR: Username/password missmatch or not exists"));

    } else if ($ext_auth['result'] == 1) {
        // External user exists, try to load the user info from the WordPress user table
        $userobj = new WP_User();
        $user    = $userobj->get_data_by('email', $ext_auth['email']); // Does not return a WP_User object
        $user    = new WP_User($user->ID); // Attempt to load up the user with that ID

        if ($user->ID == 0) {
            // The user does not currently exist in the WordPress user table.
            // So creating the user.
            // Setup the minimum required user information for this example
            $userdata    = array(
                'user_email' => $ext_auth['email'],
                'user_login' => $ext_auth['email'],
                'first_name' => $ext_auth['first_name'],
                'last_name' => $ext_auth['last_name']
            );
            $new_user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata); // A new user has been created

            // Load the new user info
            $user = new WP_User($new_user_id);
        }

    }

    return $user;
}
```

*The above code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Please Note

- As you did't share you API details, So I have't included code for that you can write the logic in *my_api_section* and it should have an $ext_auth array.
- The above code is untested but should work.

Comment: this one looks realy good. Is possible to change that way if the user is admin what proceed further to the login if not than use a preconfigured user and password? The client of mine don't want to add the usert to his database.

Comment: And I also edited my question whit the APi request, unfortunateli the request returns nothing if the user/password combination is OK and redirects to my integrated Kayako login page if they are not OK

Comment: @StoneSmith: I couldn't able to locate the redirection code in you API; but what I feel is that you should write an API which will return true/false with other parameters. and you can check the response in `my_auth` function and form there you can do the redirection. _The client of mine don't want to add the insert to his database_ :: If you do not create a WP_User then on every action you have to check the user is valid or not through custom function; moreover wp need `user_id` for various purpose, like who wrote comment or uploaded a file etc etc..